# Fedora 29 no sound from a generic usb headset

Tags: fedora, usb, audio

I bought a generic usb headset (Generic USB PnP Sound Device), it has been detected by the system, I am using Plasma KDE by the way, but it worked for me once and for about a second and then nothing. The sound was too loud, when I decrease it, the sound disappeared forever...

The headset works, i tested it on the other system ;-)

This is what dmesg reports on the device when plugged :
`[ 266.130515] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 266.261251] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1908, idProduct=2070, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 266.261257] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 266.261262] usb 1-1: Product: USB PnP Sound Device
[ 266.261265] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 266.261269] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 〲㌱㈱
[ 266.266899] input: Generic USB PnP Sound Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.3/0003:1908:2070.0004/input/input19
[ 266.319125] hid-generic 0003:1908:2070.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v2.01 Device [Generic USB PnP Sound Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input3
[ 266.501539] usb 1-1: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x2
[ 266.502698] usb 1-1: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
[ 266.512415] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[ 266.537982] usb 1-1: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
[ 266.600304] retire_capture_urb: 4 callbacks suppressed`

pactl list gives this :
`Card #2
Name: alsa_card.usb-Generic_USB_PnP_Sound_Device-00
Driver: module-alsa-card.c
Owner Module: 28
Properties:
alsa.card = "2"
alsa.card_name = "USB PnP Sound Device"
alsa.long_card_name = "Generic USB PnP Sound Device at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, full speed"
alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0"
sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/sound/card2"
udev.id = "usb-Generic_USB_PnP_Sound_Device-00"
device.bus = "usb"
device.vendor.id = "1908"
device.vendor.name = "GEMBIRD"
device.product.id = "2070"
device.product.name = "USB PnP Sound Device"
device.serial = "Generic_USB_PnP_Sound_Device"
device.string = "2"
device.description = "USB PnP Sound Device"
module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
Profiles:
input:analog-mono: Analog Mono Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 7, available: yes)
output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
output:analog-stereo+input:analog-mono: Analog Stereo Output + Analog Mono Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6507, available: yes)
output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5500, available: yes)
output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-mono: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Mono Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5507, available: yes)
off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-mono
Ports:
analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec)
Properties:
device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
Part of profile(s): input:analog-mono, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-mono, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-mono
analog-output: Analog Output (priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec)
Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-mono
iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec)
Part of profile(s): output:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-mono`

alsa-info.sh --with-devices --with-dmesg gives this :
`!!Module: snd_usb_audio
autoclock : Y
device_setup : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0
enable : Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y, Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
id : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),( null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(n ull),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(nu ll),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(nul l),(null),(null),(null)
ignore_ctl_error : N
index : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
pid : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
quirk_alias : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),( null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(n ull),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(nu ll),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(nul l),(null),(null),(null)
use_vmalloc : Y
vid : -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1

!!USB Mixer information
!!---------------------
--startcollapse--

USB Mixer: usb_id=0x19082070, ctrlif=0, ctlerr=0
Card: Generic USB PnP Sound Device at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, full speed
Unit: 2
Control: name="PCM Playback Volume", index=0
Info: id=2, control=2, cmask=0x0, channels=1, type="S16"
Volume: min=-32768, max=-32513, dBmin=-12800, dBmax=-12700
Unit: 2
Control: name="PCM Playback Switch", index=0
Info: id=2, control=1, cmask=0x0, channels=1, type="INV_BOOLEAN"
Volume: min=0, max=1, dBmin=0, dBmax=0
Unit: 5
Control: name="Mic Capture Volume", index=0
Info: id=5, control=2, cmask=0x0, channels=1, type="S16"
Volume: min=-32768, max=-29184, dBmin=-12800, dBmax=-11400
Unit: 5
Control: name="Mic Capture Switch", index=0
Info: id=5, control=1, cmask=0x0, channels=1, type="INV_BOOLEAN"
Volume: min=0, max=1, dBmin=0, dBmax=0
--endcollapse--

My system board is :
!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name: H170M-D3H
Product Version: Default string
Firmware Version: F23d
Board Vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Board Name: H170M-D3H-CF`

The device seems to be recognized, but I get nothing from it, any idea?

Comment: You decreased the sound from the buttons of the headset or in the system volume control? I ask this because I use a Logitech headset that crash the sound of the system when I use the buttons of the headset.

Comment: I did it from the system volume control, and that's it no more sound. I tested other usb ports, nothing. The other thing that is weird, the headset is equipped with a blue led that blinks when it's playing sound, when I start something like a video or a movie, the led starts blinking but there is no sound...